# ROS2 URDF: How to have multicolored things in URDF?

Tags: ros2, urdf

It seems that only the first material clause in a link is used for the whole link.

For example for a simple Minion Dave with blue overalls and yellow "body":

```
 <!-- DAVE -->
  <link name="dave_link">
    <visual name="bottom_half_dave" >
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.045" radius="0.0375" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="solid_blue" />
    </visual>

    <visual name="top_half_dave" >
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.045" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.045" radius="0.0375" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="solid_yellow" />
    </visual>

    <visual name="head_dave" >
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.625" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.0375" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="solid_yellow" />
    </visual>

  </link>
  
  <joint name="joint_dave" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="dave_link"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.04 0 0.250" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
  </joint>
```

Will always use the solid_blue of the bottom half for the other two visual objects in the dave_link.

Is there a way (other than making each part a separate link with joints)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is a bug that was [reported in 2015 and is still unresolved](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/843). The [URDF link documentation here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link) says, in part:

> **Note:** multiple instances of  tags can exist for the same link. The union of the geometry they define forms the visual representation of the link.

I don't know if the rviz bug is truly a bug or if it's *supposed* to be treating all visuals within a link as one fused object, but your options seem to be to either split out your colored components into their own links or make your own mesh and apply a texture.